# Get job input or data passed to it

Tags: powershell, azure

Suppose I want to turn off all the VMs in my subscription, I can do something like:

```
Get-AzureRmVm | Stop-AzureRmVM -Force -AsJob
```

That would happen almost instantaneously, and will create a bunch of jobs. The only problem with those Jobs is that I cant decipher what each job did. They all look the same.

```
State                : Completed
HasMoreData          : True
Location             : localhost
StatusMessage        : Completed
CurrentPSTransaction :
Host                 : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost
Command              : Stop-AzureRmVM
JobStateInfo         : Completed
Finished             : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId           : dc0da9c0-5dc7-4186-86b8-c53c21e8c690
Id                   : 2
Name                 : Long Running Operation for 'Stop-AzureRmVM'
PSJobTypeName        : AzureLongRunningJob`1
Output               : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSComputeLongRunningOperation}
Debug                : {[AzureLongRunningJob]: Starting cmdlet execution, setting for cmdlet confirmation required:
                       'False', [AzureLongRunningJob]: Completing cmdlet execution in RunJob
```

And the output looks like this:

```
OperationId :
Status      : Succeeded
StartTime   : 30/12/2017 12:03:58
EndTime     : 30/12/2017 12:04:00
Error       :
```

Which gives me no way to figure out on which VM this job was working on.
I tried looking at the job properties with `Get-Job | Get-Member -Force`, but I couldn't find anything, that would help me (command, 'jobstateinfo', information, etc). Looking at the `System.Management.Automation` Namespace also gave me no ideas on how to get that data.

I'm looking for any way to be able to inspect what gets passed to the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
$variable = my command | Add-Member @{ id = $_.Id } -PassThru
```

which I can later access like this:

```
$variable.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
State                : Completed
HasMoreData          : True
```

Looks like the jobs have finished but their output hasn't yet been returned.  You'll need the `Receive-Job` command to retrieve any output or results.

```
$Jobs = Get-AzureRmVm | Stop-AzureRmVM -Force -AsJob
$Jobs | Where-Object State -eq 'Completed' | Receive-Job -Keep
```

See `Get-Help about_Jobs`, and you'll really want to look at the parameters of the `Receive-Job` command to figure out what you want it to do.  I've also not ever used the `*-AzureRmVm` commands, so be aware of that.

Comment: That is a false, assumption, sadly. They only return that single object: `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSComputeLongRunningOperation` and that object contains no meaningful data. and yeah, I'm aware of the `rcjb` cmdlet